# Product of Geometric Brownian motions

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $S,P$ be geometric BMs:

$$dS_t=S_t(\mu dt + \sigma dW_t^1)$$
$$dP_t=P_t(\tau dt + \beta (\rho dW_t^1+ \sqrt{1-\rho^2}dW_t^2)$$

Where $W^1$ and $W^2$ are independent  standard BM.

I want to show their product is a Geometric BM.

Thanks to Did comments, I understand where I am wrong, I was working following the idea that $X_t$ is a GBM with drift $X\mu$, volatility $X\sigma$ if and only if $$d\log X_t= \mu dt + \sigma dW_t$$

while it is actually the case that $X_t$ is a GBM with drift $X\mu$ volatility $X\sigma$ iff 
$$d\log X_t= (\mu - \frac{\sigma^2}{2}) dt + \sigma dW_t$$

Using product rule, in fact, I get that the drift equals

$$\tau+\mu + \sigma \beta\rho$$

But if I try to proceed using logs I get a different answer:
starting with

$$\tag{$\star$} d(\log(PS)) = d(\log P)+ d(\log S)$$

$$ =\frac{1}{P}dP-\frac{1}{2P^2}d[P] +\frac{1}{S}dS-\frac{1}{2S^2}d[S]$$

Ignoring the volatility part I get that the drift equals:
$$ (\tau + \mu) - \frac{\beta^2 +\sigma^2}{2} $$

Which, summing the volatility squared divided by 2 gives the same result as above.

Comment: Since you do not show what you got for $d(PS)$, it is difficult to answer. Anyway, $(\star)$ is flawless.

Comment: @Did Thanks for your comment, I have updated my question!

Comment: The drift of $PS$ is $PS$ times what you write and the drift of $\log(PS)$ is what you write. What is the question? Surely you would not expect the drifts of $PS$ and $\log(PS)$ to coincide?

Comment: @Did I think I understand now, I changed again my question. I hope it is clear where my confusion came from.

Comment: So... no question left?

Comment: @did not really, I was just being stupid! I edited my question showing that there is no incongruency. Maybe it is better if I just delete it, I have left it for other people who might have the same confusion to see...